# Why don’t I die when I fall into the void in windows 10 edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Strangely, the void is blue and I dug a hole through bedrock. That is not killing me in creative mode and I could use answers.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to how the void works in the Bedrock edition. As seen [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/The_Void), the void doesn't deal damage while in Creative mode. It does, however, in Survival mode.

Answer (score -1):

Bedrock edition appears to have updated to prevent this form of death in creative, as you used to be able to die this way on an older version.